# ubuntu 12.04 does support's drivers for hcl pdc laptop or should need to search and download it from internet

Tags: 12.04

i want to shift from windows to Ubuntu but afraid a bit to search the drivers for my laptop which is hcl pdc. can any of you tell me does the Ubuntu support all type of drivers(audio,video,blue tooth)e.t.c or it will support a specific range. else do i need to search and install them after installing Ubuntu in my laptop.

any related post will be appreciated

Thanx in advance.
.....<><><><>.....

Answer (score 0):

I`m going to out on a limb here, and say that you will be safe installing Ubuntu on your system.  I have installed Ubuntu on many different systems from a PIII system to Core i7, with different hardware configuration, and had no problem whatsoever.  So I say go ahead, and welcome to Ubuntu :)